# How to get Percentage form progressbar opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I have an image like that

Image: https://snag.gy/O5sjcp.jpg

I want to calculate the percentage of progress bar using OpenCV.

Here is what I did
I cropped the Image and applied binary threshold but this fails as in following image:
https://snag.gy/HNKXxQ.jpg

```
frame = frame[y: y + h, x: x + w]
_,frame = cv2.threshold(frame,1,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

Any Idea?
Code is appreciated

Comment: What have you tried so far? Code is appreciated.

Comment: You can add your image to question. Seems the downloaded image is blank [https://snag.gy/O5sjcp.jpg](https://snag.gy/O5sjcp.jpg).

Comment: actually, I am unable to upload the image to StackOverflow.

Comment: It gives an error

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector<cv::Mat> channels;
cv::split(img,channels);

img = channels[1]-channels[2]-channels[0];
cv::threshold(img,img,100,255,CV_THRESH_OTSU);
cv::bitwise_not(img,img);
```

That one should leave white numbers on black background. Then you could proceed with `cv::findContours` for example.

Comment: can you explain whats going on??